# Access my GigE Camera with Python (by IP address)

Tags: python, ip, ip-address, ethernet, flir

Hy guys, I need help to access my FLIR camera data.
I connect the camera to the pc by an Ethernet cable.
I go to my Local Netwrok connection and configure, in Internet protocol version 4.

Use the following IP address:
IP address: 192.168.2.10
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.2.1
The IP of the camera is 192.168.2.2
But i still can't access the image from the camera.

Comment: Can you ping the camera? Please show your code you use to grab images from the camera.

Comment: Do you connect the camera directly to your computer or is it connected to your local network

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
Yes i can ping the camera, and i connect the camera directly to my computer. 
Meanwhile i can talk to the supplier , and he told me that i can't access this speficic cameras by the IP Address. 
What i need to solve my problem is SpinView, Spinnaker SDK and a library named PySpin. I'm Know available to acquire images from the camera.

Comment: But now, i have a new problem. I just can run my Acquire.py by cmd window. I'm not available to run it with the software Pycharm where i have the rest of my project. 
I know that i have to import or install that specific library in my software. I'm having several dificulties with that, anyone know how can i do that?